# Ubuntu on Apple hardware (early 2011 MacBook Pro)

Tags: linux, macbook-pro

This isn't so much a "how do I install Linux on Apple hardware" question, but rather a "could this do any sort of damage" one.

I've heard a few people speak of "burning out" the Apple hardware by installing a non-Apple operating system on the computer. In specific, I've heard it has to do with OS X and the way it manages CPU voltages via the SMC, and how a non-Apple OS does not interact with the SMC in a similar way, which in turn puts the CPU under too much load for too long a time, and burns it out.

I've done some research online, and haven't heard any mention of this being possible, but I'm curious if anyone has any experience in killing a Mac by installing Linux (specifically Ubuntu, or Fedora).

tl;dr – can installing Linux bare-metal on my MacBook Pro (early 2011, i7 13") have any ill effects on my hardware?

Answer (score 3):

The explanation you've heard is highly suspect. While installing an alternate OS might (if you're not careful) hose the partition table on your hard drive, I *highly* doubt you'd accidentally over-volt the CPU so hard it breaks.

There *might* be issues with power management (or a lack thereof) running the CPU too hot and not running the fans at full-tilt, but that oughtn't ruin the machine.

Comment: im not overly concerned with partition tables, as i plan on having linux as the primary (and only) OS on the MBP. the only reason i question this is the information comes from a former apple "genius" and fellow sysadmin. the only document referencing the above i could find, was written by the colleague in question. sometimes, its tough to sort out the propaganda from the facts ;) i personally have never heard of an OS damaging hardware by simply running.

Comment: @adam I mentioned that as the most likely cause I could think of of someone thinking they'd hosed their computer. If you know what partition tables are enough to not be worried with a good reason, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a distro called Yellow Dog which is supposed to work with Mac systems. It is designed for Mac, but what I have seen on most modern day Macs that the kernel is Linux 2.4. So burning out a system with a Linux distro seems kind of odd. Mac like these are designed from Unix, if these work that would mean that BSD will work too. Best way is to check out a site called http://distrowatch.com. Here they have plenty of distributions to pick from.

Comment: Yellow Dog is designed to work on PowerPC systems. No Mac with a PPC processor has been sold for nearly six years. Sure it'll work with older systems, but I don't believe they ever made the Intel transition.

Comment: +1 @CajunLuke on that one. this is an intel i7 MBP. my end goal is to run awesomeWM. (truthfully, if i could have awesomeWM running instead of OSX chrome, i wouldnt need to install ubuntu to begin with)

Answer (score 0):

I just recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a 2011 MacBook Pro and everything just works. Ubuntu 20.04 is very mature for installing onto a 2011 MacBook Pro. Prior to doing the upgrade I watched a couple YouTube vids on the subject as well as spent about an hour reading about the specifics, and it's the best thing I've ever done on this 2011 MacBook Pro. I opted for Ubuntu Linux ONLY on this laptop and gave the entire disk to it. If your attempting to do this in 2021 it will work.

Oh, and as pertains to the OP's original question; I spent a couple hours today watching YouTube vids on this subject and reading the top 10 or so Google entries prior to doing the upgrade. Other than a caveat in running the battery down faster if you decide to use both video cards, I didn't run across anything that would break the hardware, and there's a reliable method for hardware disabling the discrete gfx card dGPU which get's around that issue. I have both video cards enabled at the moment and on full charge the battery tells me it has just over 4 hours left, and I can live with that.

Ron

Comment: I added that post as the thread is 9 years old and I just recently performed this and it works very well. Man I love my new LinuxBook. (Easrly 2011 MBP, 16gb RAM, 512gb SSD, nice!) - Ron